# Admob- Adding new ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, admob

I'm fairly new to xcode, but I'm having some trouble adding admob to my app.

I followed the instructions for Admob but the ads are not showing up.

I'm thinking I need to add the new view I created AdViewController to appsdelegate. Is there a code I should add for that?

BTW: I'm using a tabbar controller as the rootviewcontroller

Comment: you just have initialize the admobe view and add it as subview of your view.

Comment: where do u want to show the admobviewcontroller

Comment: not sure how to initialize the admob view and add it as a subview.

Comment: i want to show the admobviewcontroller on every page

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048835/how-do-i-initialize-admob-and-set-the-subview

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to create something akin to a singleton `GADBannerView`. My recommendation would be just to create a `GADBannerView` object that you pass around through different view controllers but constantly have the `UITabBarController` as your `rootViewController`.

There's an example that uses a UITabBar solution at http://code.google.com/p/google-mobile-dev/source/browse/AdCatalog/Classes/AdvancedLayoutUseCases/TabbedViewExample/?repo=adcatalog-ios.