# How do I initialize Admob and set the subview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, admob

I'm fairly new to xcode, but i'm having some trouble adding admob to my app.

I followed the instructions for Admob but the ads are not showing up.

Im thinking i need to add the new view i created AdViewController to appsdelegate. Is there a code i should add for that?

BTW: Im using a tabbar controller as the rootviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

In the view controller in which you want to display the add , do the following :

.h

```
@interface MyViewController: UIViewController
{
  GADBannerView *adBanner;
}

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation MyViewController

// In the viewDidLoad method of the controller create a adbanner
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  adBanner_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, GAD_SIZE_320x50.width, GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];
  adBanner_.delegate = self;
  adBanner_.rootViewController = self;
  adBanner_.adUnitID = the_ad_ID_given_by_Google;
  GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
  [adBanner loadRequest:request];

  [self.view addSubview:adBanner];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `rootViewController` to be the `UITabBarController`, but you need to add the `GADBannerView` object into the view for the view Controller that's currently being shown.

There's an example using a custom UITabBar solution [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-mobile-dev/source/browse/AdCatalog/Classes/AdvancedLayoutUseCases/TabbedViewExample/?repo=adcatalog-ios).